# i keep getting ValueError: array length 2643 does not match index length 3281

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here my code:

```
# AnyNan values in the target column or in my dataset
training_data.dropna(inplace=True, axis=0)
testing_data.dropna(inplace=True, axis=0)

# Perform one hot encoding on HomePlanet, 

features = ['HomePlanet', 'Destination', 'CryoSleep', 'VIP' ]
X= pd.get_dummies(training_data[features]).astype(int)
y = pd.get_dummies(training_data.Transported).astype(int)
x_test = testing_data[features]

# Creating my model

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, train_size=0.6, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)
rt_model = RandomForestRegressor()
rt_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = rt_model.predict(X_test)

#save the csv

output = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': testing_data.PassengerId, 'Transported': predictions})
output.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
print("Your submission was successfully saved!")
```

When I print the length of `X` , `y`  and `X_train`, `y_train` after train-test split I get:

```
6606 6606
3963 3963
2643 2643
```

I tried reshaping X and y.

I tried performing one hot Encoding on my `x_test dataframe`.

I did the `iloc` method on my array.

The problem only comes from the last part trying to save it as a `csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first two lines, I assume that you already have testing data provided. There is no need to split the training data into additional testing data.

Therefore, your predictions should run on the provided test data `x_test` not the splitted `X_test`. Note that Python is case sensitive and naming variables like this is confusing and risks mixing up variables.

As you use `X_test`, `predictions` is an array with a different length than your `testing_data` and you have therefore a length mismatch when you create a DataFrame from `testing_data` and `predictions` and try to save this DataFrame.

So using

```py
predictions = rt_model.predict(x_test) # lowercase x
```

should work but I would change the code further and get rid of your additional split of the data as you throw away training data.